# jQuery extracting data using filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get content inside a div in another pages.

```
$.get('page1.php', function(data){
  //option 1 <-- Cannot get content in a div inside a div, but can get root-div content
  var content = $(data).filter('#bar').html();

 //option 2 <-- Cannot get root-div content, but can get content in a div inside a div
 var content = $('#bar', data).html();
});
```

I have noticed a problem, if I use `filter` function to extract data, I will not be able to get the content of a div inside a root-div. For example to get the content in id `bar` with this code: `$(data).filter('#bar').html();`

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">
  Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

However, If i use `$('#bar', data).html()`, I can retrieve the content inside bar, BUT I can't retrieve the content of `foo` for example `('#foo', data).html()`.

Are there any functions where you can combined these 2 situations instead of using these 2 methods together?

Comment: Just use `$(data).html()` to get the root element's inner HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give an example with `data` specified, to make it clear what behavior you're expecting.
From what you wrote, I'm supposing you're trying to use `filter` to select from the children of a div. It won't work, because `filter` selects from the objects in the current selection, it doesn't care
what is inside those objects. So, if you have `div#foo` in your selection, it won't care about `div#bar` inside it.

So, this works:

```
$("#foo").filter("#foo").html()
```

But it won't work

```
$("#foo").filter("#bar").html()
```

because `div#bar` is not in the selection from which you're trying to filter. It could work this way:

```
$("#foo").children().filter("#bar").html()
```

In case I misunderstood your question, I apologise, and will gladly update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! so `$("#foo").children().filter("#bar").html()` is basically the same as `$('#bar', data).html();`. I'm making a small web app that allows users to input their desired <div> element to retrieve its content, does that mean I have to check if the div has children then I need to use .children.filter(), and if not then use filter()?

Comment: Why would you like to filter the children? If your clients specify their div, and you want to retrieve its content, then just use `$div.html()`. Its use is to retrieve the content of an element.

Comment: What is the input exactly? If it is a selector string, like "#foo", then all you need to do is `$("#foo").html()`. So, if `data` stands for something like "#foo", then use `$(data).html()`.